# Apache URL rewrite and redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to rewrite my url to a new path. From:

```
www.example.com/test.php?name=xxxx&id=xxxx
```

To:

```
 www.example.com/test-namevalue-idvalue
```

When I typed `www.example.com/test.php?name=xxxx&id=xxxx` in browser, it will take a while to redirect to page `www.example.com/test-namevalue-idvalue`, but browser complains the website is in redirecting loop. So, I am wondering someone has also met this kind of issue before?

Here is the content of my .htaccess file for Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^name=(.*)&id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ /test-%1-%2? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^test-(.*)-([0-9]+)$ test.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try matching against the actual request instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+test\.php\?name=([^&]+)&id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /test-%1-%2? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^test-(.*)-([0-9]+)$ test.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, Jon Lin, Thanks. I have tried your configuration, and the url will load the page, but the only thing is, when I typed in the original url: www.example.com/test.php?name=xxx&id=xxx, the page will not be redirect as www.example.com/test-namevalue-idvalue.

Comment: @David_Wang Sorry, the `%id` should have been `&id`. Also make sure to clear your browser's cache

Comment: Thanks Jon, it works as charm~ It took me almost 4 hours on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I vaguely remember that I would intuitively set the flags of the last `RewriteRule` to `[PT,L]` instead of just `[L]`. Maybe you try that.

Comment: Thanks Roland, but the PT flag is not working, still redirection loop.